# Change figure window title in pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I set a figure window's title in pylab/python?

```
fig = figure(9) # 9 is now the title of the window
fig.set_title("Test") #doesn't work
fig.title = "Test" #doesn't work
```

Comment: `plt.suptitle('figure title')` and `plt.gcf().canvas.set_window_title('window title')` and `plt.figure('window title')`

Comment: Note that plt.figure() seem to act differently than canvas.manager.set_window_title( fig_name ). Canvas will not modify the labels as returned by plt.get_figlabels(). You can also not acces the figure later on by doing plt.figure(fig_name)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

If you want to actually change the window you can do:

```
fig = pylab.gcf()
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Test')
```

**Update 2021-05-15:**

The solution above is deprecated [(see here)](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/api_changes.html). instead use

```
fig = pylab.gcf()
fig.canvas.manager.set_window_title('Test')
```

Comment: Not working. I have multiple figures that will be shown. Also, I'm importing pylab via `from pylab import *` and `pylab.title("test")` and `title("test")` don't work.

Comment: I use this code: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx5_sgskip.html  and wonder how to rename a matplotlib figure here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 66):

You can also set the window title when you create the figure:

```
fig = plt.figure("YourWindowName")
```

Comment: From the docs: `If num is a string, the window title will be set to this figure's num.`

I see most people pass in a number, so passing in the title directly would be so much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 39):

Based on Andrew' answer, if you use pyplot instead of pylab, then:

```
fig = pyplot.gcf()
fig.canvas.set_window_title('My title')
```

Comment: `Warning: The set_window_title function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use manager.set_window_title or GUI-specific methods instead.`

Answer (score 21):

I used `fig.canvas.set_window_title('The title')` with `fig` obtained with `pyplot.figure()` and it worked well too:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
fig = plt.figure(0)
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Window 3D')
```

[image]

(Seems `.gcf()` and `.figure()` does similar job here.)

Comment: Looks like `.figure()` create a new `figure` whereas `.gcf()` stands for get current figure which is what it does actually.

Comment: Ibrahim's comment should be edited into the answer. Also: `Warning: The set_window_title function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use manager.set_window_title or GUI-specific methods instead.`

Comment: plt.figure('1') seem to act differently than canvas.manager.set_window_title( fig_name ). Canvas will not modify the labels as returned by plt.get_figlabels(). You can also not acces the figure later on by doing plt.figure(fig_name)

Answer (score 7):

I found this was what I needed for pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
....
plt.get_current_fig_manager().canvas.set_window_title('My Figure Name')
```

Comment: Useful when using state-based `plt.subplot()` which doesn't give a `fig` object

Answer (score 6):

I have found that using the `canvas` object, as in these two examples:

```
fig.canvas.set_window_title('My title')
```

as suggested by some other answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30008529/4424636), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37762878/4424636)), and

```
plt.get_current_fig_manager().canvas.set_window_title('My Figure Name')
```

from [benjo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66042751/4424636), both give this warning:

```
The set_window_title function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use manager.set_window_title or GUI-specific methods instead.
```

The solution seems to be to adapt [Benjo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66042751/4424636) and use:

```
plt.get_current_fig_manager().set_window_title('My Figure Name')
```

That is to say drop the use of `canvas`. This gets rid of the warning.

Answer (score 5):

Code that works now (09.04.23, matplotlib 3.7.1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,4,6,8,10]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().set_window_title('My Figure Name')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

From Matplotlib 3.4 and later the function `set_window_title` was deprecated.

You can use `matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle()` which behaves like `set_window_title`.

See: [matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html)