# Bidirectional Bar Plot in python, how to remove all background colours?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I wrote this code (using [this](https://sharkcoder.com/data-visualization/mpl-bidirectional) example):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
#sns.set()
#%matplotlib notebook
#plt.style.use('classic')

class_list = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6','test7']
data = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(class_list,average_length,num_entries),columns=['Class','Lens','Nums'])
data.set_index('Class', inplace=True)

font_color = '#525252'
hfont = {'fontname':'Calibri'}
#facecolor = '#eaeaf2'
color_red = '#fd625e'
color_blue = '#01b8aa'
index = data.index
column0 = data['Lens']
column1 = data['Nums']
title0 = "Title 1"
title1 = 'Title 2'

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5), facecolor=facecolor, ncols=2,sharey=True)
fig.tight_layout()

axes[0].barh(index, column0, align='center', color=color_red, zorder=10)
axes[0].set_title(title0, fontsize=18, pad=15, color=color_red, **hfont)
axes[1].barh(index, column1, align='center', color=color_blue, zorder=10)
axes[1].set_title(title1, fontsize=18, pad=15, color=color_blue, **hfont)


# If you have positive numbers and want to invert the x-axis of the left plot
axes[0].invert_xaxis() 


# To show data from highest to lowest
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

axes[0].set(yticks=data.index, yticklabels=data.index)
axes[0].yaxis.tick_left()
axes[0].tick_params(axis='y', colors='white') # tick color

axes[1].set_xticklabels(['0','20', '40', '60', '80', '100', '120'])


for label in (axes[0].get_xticklabels() + axes[0].get_yticklabels()):
    label.set(fontsize=13, color=font_color, **hfont)
for label in (axes[1].get_xticklabels() + axes[1].get_yticklabels()):
    label.set(fontsize=13, color=font_color, **hfont)
    
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, top=0.85, bottom=0.1, left=0.18, right=0.95)
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

I want to remove all the background colours (so there's no 'Figure 1', no white gridlines and the background is pure white instead of blue-y purple), and then just add a  black line on the x and y axis.

When I try to add an x and y axis line with this:

```
plt.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')
plt.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')
```

There's no error, but there's no graph either.

Edit 1:
Adding

```
axes[0].set_facecolor('white')
axes[1].set_facecolor('white')
```

Worked for removing the background colours. I also tried to add x and y axis lines via:

```
axes[0].axvline(0)
axes[0].axhline(0)
```

This produces a line mid-way through the bottom bar:

[image]

(and 'Figure 1' is still there).

Comment: `sns.set_style('white')`?  And just remove the calls to `.set_title`? Did you try anything or did you just blindly copy?

Comment: Thanks a mil for that. I added some thing I've tried as an Edit above. Thanks. I don't think the `.set_title` works (but am happy to be wrong), because what I'm trying to remove is the bar across the top of the graph that says 'Figure 1', but I don't define that in the script so I guess that's a default setting.

Comment: To change the title of the window: `fig.canvas.manager.set_window_title('')` see [Change figure window title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812960/change-figure-window-title-in-pylab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `facecolor` is responsible for the background color. You can remove it to have white background.

Use `set_window_title` to add a new title to the window.

Modified code looks like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5), ncols=2,sharey=True) # Removed facecolor param
fig.tight_layout()
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Custom Title') # Adds new title to the window
```

Comment: Thanks a mil, can I just ask about the `.set_window_title()`, you can see from my output there's a grey bar with 'Figure 1' in it, but 'Figure 1' doesn't appear anywhere in my code at all right.  So  `.set_window_title()` doesn't seem to change it? Ideally I'd like to completely remove the 'Figure 1' bar at the top of the plot, but I can't see what parameter I call to invoke it, but changing `.set_window_title()` doesn't seem to change it?

Comment: Can you try to save the plot using `fig.savefig('plot.pdf')`. That will save only the main plotting area. The grey bar you see is generally for navigation purpose and I am not sure how you would minimize or close the plot without that grey bar.

Comment: Thanks a mil, that's perfect.